# Change sub-menu contents of main menu

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have main-menu and another menu saved as second-menu. I want to programmatically update the contents of main-menu by adding the items in second-menu to the main-menu of submenu 'shop' (and of course remove the existing ones). There will be several 'second menus' and the contents will change based on the logic that is not interesting here.

The following code does not work, it will create broken menu items:

```
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items', 'custom_shop_menu', 10, 2);

function custom_shop_menu($items, $args) {
  $menu_name = "main-menu";
  $menu_obj = get_term_by('name', $menu_name, 'nav_menu');
  $menu_id = $menu_obj->term_id;
  $menu_items = wp_get_nav_menu_items($menu_id);

  foreach ($menu_items as $menu_item) {
    if (strtolower($menu_item->title) == "shop") {
      $submenu_obj = get_term_by('name', "second-menu", 'nav_menu');
      $submenu_id = $submenu_obj->term_id;
      $submenu_items = wp_get_nav_menu_items($submenu_id);
      foreach ($submenu_items as $submenu_item) {
        $itemData =  array(
          'menu-item-parent-id' => $menu_item->ID,
          'menu-item-type' => $submenu_item->type,
          'menu-item-title' => $submenu_item->title,
          'menu-item-url' => $submenu_item->url,
          'menu-item-description' => $submenu_item->description,
          'menu-item-attr-title' => $submenu_item->attr-title,
          'menu-item-target' => $submenu_item->target,
          'menu-item-classes' => $submenu_item->classes,
          'menu-item-xfn' => $submenu_item->xfn,
          'menu-item-status' => $submenu_item->status
        );
        wp_update_nav_menu_item($menu_id, $submenu_item->db-id, $itemData);
      }
      break;
    }
  }
  return $items;
}
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: how about doing it with javascript?

Comment: There is a site for WordPress development questions : http://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Comment: Any examples how to do this in javascript? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I did this by copying the title and url from the another menu to the main-menu. In this way I can maintain several 'another menus' and update the needed part (=products) of the main-menu based on the certain logic (in this case based on the get_site_vorigin()).

```
add_filter('wp_get_nav_menu_items', 'custom_get_nav_menu_items', 10, 2);

function custom_get_nav_menu_items($items, $menu, $args) {
  if($menu->slug != 'main-menu') { // only for main-menu
    return $items;
  }

  $start_replacing = false;
  $counter = 0;

  $submenu_items = get_sub_menu_items(get_site_vorigin());

  foreach ($items as $item) {
    if ($start_replacing) {
      $inner_counter = 0;
      foreach ($submenu_items as $submenu_item) {
        if ($inner_counter == $counter) {
          $item->title = $submenu_item->title;
          $item->url = $submenu_item->url;
          $item->description = $submenu_item->description;
          $item->target = $submenu_item->target;
        }
        $inner_counter++;
      }
      $counter++;
    }
    if (strtolower($item->title) == 'products') {
      $start_replacing = true;
    }
  }

  return $items;
}

function get_sub_menu_items($submenu_name) {
  $submenu_obj = get_term_by('name', $submenu_name, 'nav_menu');
  $submenu_id = $submenu_obj->term_id;
  return wp_get_nav_menu_items($submenu_obj->term_id);
}
```